# Android: Unable to set values in layout file programmatically

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

I am trying to add Text to textview's and Radio buttons programmatically in my layout file. I have debugged the application and saw the correct values are returned from the cursor but i am unable to bind these values to the textview's.

**Issue in displayquestions function**

```
package com.Example.assesmenttool;


public class Aptitude extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    DBHelper helper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Button btnBegin,btnnext;
    int count = 0;

    //Sub category Buttons
    Button btnaptitude5,btnaptitude4,btnaptitude3,btnaptitude2,btnaptitude1;

    String Question_ID,Title,TitleDescription,QuestionText,QuestionTemplate,QuestionImage;

    //String SubModuleQuestion_ID;

    TextView tvTitle,tvInstructions,tvQuestionText;

    RadioGroup rgtemplate4images;
    ImageView img;
     RelativeLayout aptitudesubcateg,temp4optimage;



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.aptitude);

          aptitudesubcateg = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.aptitudesubcateg);
          temp4optimage = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.temp4optimage);


         aptitudesubcateg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         temp4optimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        btnaptitude1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaptitude1);
        btnaptitude2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaptitude2);
        btnaptitude3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaptitude3);
        btnaptitude4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaptitude4);
        btnaptitude5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaptitude5);

        btnaptitude1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnaptitude2.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnaptitude3.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnaptitude4.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnaptitude5.setOnClickListener(this);

        helper=new DBHelper(this);
        //Resources res = getResources();
        //String[] myBooks = res.getStringArray(R.array.my_questions);



        btnBegin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBeginAptitude);

        btnBegin.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

     public int getcount(String moduleID, String SubModuleID)
     {
         count = 0;
         String selectQuery = "Select * from TableQuestionMaster where Module_ID = "+moduleID+" AND SubModule_ID ="+SubModuleID;

            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            count =  cursor.getCount();

            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(count) ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

            cursor.close();
            db.close();

    return count; 
     }



       public void getAllQuestionsAptitude(String moduleID, String SubModuleID,String SubModuleQuestion_ID){



           SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
           Cursor c = null;

           if (count>0)
            {

           //   SubModuleQuestion_ID = "1";
                   String selectQuestion = "Select * from TableQuestionMaster where Module_ID = "+moduleID+" AND SubModule_ID ="+SubModuleID+" AND SubModuleQuestion_ID ="+SubModuleQuestion_ID;
                      c = db.rawQuery(selectQuestion, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {


                    Question_ID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Question_ID")); 

                    Title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Title"));


                    TitleDescription = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("TitleDescription"));


                    QuestionText = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("QuestionText"));


                    QuestionTemplate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("QuestionTemplate"));


                    QuestionImage = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("QuestionImage"));

                    Toast.makeText(this,Question_ID+" "+Title+" "+TitleDescription+" "+QuestionText+" "+QuestionTemplate+" "+QuestionImage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                } while (c.moveToNext());        
            }
            }
            else

            {
                 Toast.makeText(this,"NO question to display",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }


            // closing connection
            c.close();
            db.close();

        }

       public void displayquestions()
       {
           Toast.makeText(this,"count on display Q is"+ count,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           if (count >0)
           {
               getAllQuestionsAptitude("1","1",String.valueOf(count));

                    aptitudesubcateg.setVisibility(View.GONE);      
                    temp4optimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
                    tvTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTitleTemplate4optoinsImage);
                    tvInstructions = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInstructionstemplate4);
                    tvQuestionText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvQuestionTextTemplate4Image);

                    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewtemplate4options);

                    tvTitle.setText(Title);
                    tvInstructions.setText(TitleDescription);
                    tvQuestionText.setText(QuestionText);

                    String imgName = QuestionImage; // specify here your image name fetched from db
                    String uri = "drawable/" + imgName;
                    int icon = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, "drawable", getPackageName());
                    img.setImageResource(icon);

                    //NextQuestion();
           }
           else
           {
               Toast.makeText(this,"NO question to display",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }


       }

       public void NextQuestion()
       {
           if (count>0)
           {
           count = count - 1;
           displayquestions();
           }

       }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (v==btnBegin)
        {
             aptitudesubcateg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              temp4optimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }       
            if (v== btnaptitude1)
            {               
                      getcount("1", "1");
                      displayquestions();          

            }

            if (v== btnaptitude2)
            {
                  getcount("1", "2");
                  displayquestions();
            //  getAllQuestionsAptitude("1","2");
            }

            if (v== btnaptitude3)
            {
                  getcount("1", "3");
                  displayquestions();

                //getAllQuestionsAptitude("1","3");
            }

            if (v== btnaptitude4)
            {
            //  getAllQuestionsAptitude("1","1");
                 getcount("1", "4");
                 displayquestions();
            }

            if (v== btnaptitude5)
            {
            //  getAllQuestionsAptitude("1","1");
                 getcount("1", "5");
                 displayquestions();
            }           


        }



    }
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvInstructionsAptitude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvQuestionTextTemplate4Image"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_marginTop="93dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam nibh ex, elementum non bibendum ac, consequat a sem. Proin aliquet arcu id lacus interdum, sed fermentum neque sollicitudin. Vestibulum mauris massa, vulputate tincidunt quam vel, egestas tincidunt nisi. Ut ut nulla sagittis, aliquet lectus vitae, pretium nisi. Duis maximus, magna vitae ultricies consectetur, ex felis congue turpis, id scelerisque nisl ex at turpis. Aenean dui sapien, euismod at sem non, rhoncus molestie urna. Mauris condimentum risus felis, nec iaculis orci accumsan nec. Vivamus pharetra ultricies quam a aliquam. Praesent facilisis turpis malesuada massa interdum consequat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer efficitur nibh risus, ac mattis mi porta ut. Nam leo ex, pulvinar eu orci vel, pretium maximus velit. Pellentesque rhoncus sapien felis, in cursus eros malesuada imperdiet."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvQuestionTextTemplate4Image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Instructions"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvQuestionTextTemplate4Image"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvQuestionTextTemplate4Image"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:text="Time : 10 Mins"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBeginAptitude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvInstructionsAptitude"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvInstructionsAptitude"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvInstructionsAptitude"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="Begin" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/aptitudesubcateg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        layout="@layout/aptitudesubcategory" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/temp4optimage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/template4optionsimage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Outcome**

[image: As u can the values are coming in toast but are unable to set them]

Comment: what is the outcome?

Comment: Getting any error?And why are you initializing textviews in the displayquestions() functions instead of onCreate() method

Comment: Narrow out the code for the changing you have problems it

Comment: I have updated the question with outcome image

Comment: @Soham No Sir no errors, But as u can see question text is not setting. The values in toast should be binded to the textviews in the layout in outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try once by putting the below lines in the `oncreate()` method instead of `displayquestions()`?

```
            tvTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTitleTemplate4optoinsImage);
            tvInstructions = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInstructionstemplate4);
            tvQuestionText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvQuestionTextTemplate4Image);

            img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewtemplate4options);
```

Comment: i m trying something else as of now

Comment: I think two textviews with same ID exist in different layouts which is causing all thjis troublre

Comment: yes i tried it.. same result... The value in string is unable to bind with textview

Comment: @tusharnarang,do one thing send me your project.I will look into it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83742/discussion-between-tushar-narang-and-soham).

Comment: Yes but stuck.. When the count is greater than one the question text sets as blank.. Cab u share what u did yesterday

Comment: @tusharnarang please share your email,sorry about yesterday couldn't contact you

Comment: tushar.nrng@gmail.com

Comment: I have shared with you.Please check mail and we can chat

Answer (score 1):

If your `cursor` returns only one row(which i guess it does by looking at your `query`) you **don't need a loop**, by writing in a loop your `strings` are being initialized but they are being over written by new values.

Comment: so What should i write instead of cursor move to next ?

Comment: yes you are absolutely right my cursor gets only one row..  but one of the three parameters change on button click

Comment: You can try

 `if(cursor!=null  && cursor.getCount()>0){ 
// do your stuff
}`